# C# Lists, Foreach, and Types

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a version of foreach that checks only for a specific type and returns it.

For example consider this class tree:

org.clixel.ClxBasic -> org.clixel.ClxObject -> org.clixel.ClxSprite -> WindowsGame1.test

Then consider this code

```
public List<ClxBasic> objects = new List<ClxBasic>();

foreach(GroupTester tester in objects)
{
    tester.GroupTesterOnlyProperty = true;
}
```

tester.GroupTesterOnlyProperty is a property created in GroupTester. Is there some way to make something like this work, like an overload of foreach, or another snippet that might help me? I want to make it easy for a programmer to sort through the lists grabbing only what type they need.

Comment: @Killercam: `objects` is already a `List<T>`, which implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: GroupTester doesn't appear in your class hierarchy. How do you expect to cast 'objects' to an unrelated type ?

Comment: In this case why are you not using something like `foreach(ClxBasic basic in objects) ...`?

Comment: Oops, I meesed that up, GroupTester is related to ClxSprite. I meant to write it as Test and then make GroupTester be Test in the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` objects.

Your loop could then look like this:

```
foreach(GroupTester tester in objects.OfType<GroupTester>())
{
    tester.GroupTesterOnlyProperty = true;
}
```

**Note:** This assumes that `GroupTester` inherits from `ClxBasic`.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(GroupTester tester in objects.OfType<GroupTester>())
{
    tester.GroupTesterOnlyProperty = true;
}
```

As suggested by @ThePower (and then deleted), you could iterate over all objects and check the type explicitly:

```
foreach(var tester in objects)
{
    if (tester is GroupTester)
    {
       (tester as GroupTester).GroupTesterOnlyProperty = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! I'll keep this little snippet around for later use.

Comment: Aww change it back, the other one was very useful!

Comment: @user406470 I didn't change this in any way since I posted it :)

Comment: Weird, someone left an answer with a cool way to check the type of an object using if(x is ClxBasic)

Comment: @user406470 that is true; I've posted their answer so you can see it. I added the cast `tester as GroupTester` to make it work.